# MySQL RELOAD and RESET QUERY CACHE

Tags: mysql, caching, phpmyadmin, reload

I'm using phpmyadmin and working on someone site whose information is pulled from a database with a table called "profile_types" I had to add a row for a new type but the website isn't reflecting the changes. I've been reading around and "have query cache" is set to yes so figured I should clear the cache and see if that helps any.

So after reading I was trying to use RESET QUERY CACHEl but kept getting an error about using RELOAD> So after some more reading I can't figure out how to use the RELOAD command. As far as I know this is the databases only user account so I'd figured it was admin and had the necessary privs. Am I missing something? Also, do you guys thinks doing the RESET QUERY CACHE would maybe allow it to update the site with the new record? I've cleared my browsers cache and tried all that and no go so figured this was my last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query cache is for the results of selects. It doesn't "cache" inserts - if queries were stuck into the cache and then not reflected in subsequent results, the database wouldn't be ACID compliant.

In other words, imagine if this was a banking database, and it "cached" deposits but made sure withdrawals were reflected immediately. You'd be drowning in overdrafts. Oh... wait... That's how banks work these days.

Comment: But the query to populate the options is a SELECT. I inserted the new record manually. My SELECT though to populate the options from the table is like "SELECT ptitle,pid FROM profile_types ORDER BY id ASC" and it's not adding the new option. I read some more and found out how to Grant privileges and attempted to grant the reload privlege but it wouldnt let me.

Comment: Then add error checking too all your queries. At BARE MINIMUM your database calls should look something like `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`. If data isn't coming out of the database, then most likely it's not going INTO the database in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what is in my code to returnthe results. As I said it returns all the records that were in there. I added a new option last night though and it's night. So I'm fairly confident this is probably just a query cache issue and not a coding issue since it is returning all the other records fine. Thanks for the tips thus far however.